# SSH using RSA keys - Permission denied

Tags: ssh, cygwin, rsa, private-key, public-key

From `MACHINE_2`, as `USER1`, I need to SSH into `MACHINE_1` without having to provide a password.

I created a pair of RSA keys (`private_key`, `public_key`) using the command `C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

I have put the two files `private_key` and `public_key` in the folder `C:\cygwin64\home\USER1\.ssh\machines_1_2\`.

On `MACHINE_1`, I copied the contents of the `public_key` file into the file `D:\cygwin\home\USER1\.ssh\authorized_keys`.

On `MACHINE_2`, I created the file `C:\cygwin64\home\USER1\.ssh\config` in which I put the following lines:

```
Host 192.168.77.45
  Port 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/machines_1_2/private_key
```

When I try to SSH into `MACHINE_1`, I get a "Permission denied" message (see the output below).

```
USER1@MACHINE_2$ ssh -v 192.168.77.45
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.77.45 [192.168.77.45] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.77.45:22 as 'MACHINE_1+USER1'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:qSH/p+CitL49lw4RPcwmVd8P+e02Ot1yjTSagmyiZhA
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.77.45' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/USER1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
MACHINE_1+USER1@192.168.77.45: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

I was wondering if there was not a confusion between the two ".ssh" directories:
`C:\cygwin64\home\USER1\.ssh\` and `C:\Users\USER1\.ssh\`
Personally, I always usually deal with the `C:\cygwin64\home\USER1\.ssh\` directory... not the other one.

Also, `MACHINE_1` and `MACHINE_2` are two "Windows" machines with "Cygwin" installed.
On `MACHINE_1`, the cygwin version is 3.3.4.
On `MACHINE_2`, the cygwin version is 1.7.33.

Can you help me investigate what's going wrong?

**============= Edit 1 ================**

I installed a new Cygwin (v. 3.3.4) on `MACHINE_2`.

I still have the same problem.

**============= Edit 2 ================**

It looks like the `config` file is not been read.

**============= Edit 3 ================**

I put the `config` file and the `machines_1_2` directory in the `C:\Users\USER1\.ssh\` directory instead of the `C:\cygwin64\home\USER1\.ssh\` directory.

It allowed me to SSH into `MACHINE_1` without having to enter a password.

Until this day, I always used the `C:\cygwin64\home\USER1\.ssh\` directory...

As I could understand:

```
$ set | grep HOME
HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/USER1
```

`/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are no longer automatically generated since version 1.7.34.
In my older Cygwin configuration (the version 1.7.33), the user's home directory was set to `/home/USER1` that is to say `C:\cygwin64\home\USER1`

I guess developers have good reasons for making such changes but for people like me it takes precious time and nerves to fix the problems and that does not make my work more fun or interesting. It makes me feel stupid. My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Recent version openssh remove rsa support by default, so you should enable it in your ssh config:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
    Host *
         HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
         PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```